# Elements in array or vector changing c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to do a homework, where I read names from console / .txt file, but every time it reads an line, the whole array / vector changes to that specific line, the elements don't stay the same.. and I can't move any further
Posting all of my code

Pretakar.h

```
    #pragma once
class Pretekar
{
public:
    Pretekar(const char* priezvisko, const char* meno, const char pohlavie, unsigned int startCislo, int dosiahCas);
    Pretekar();
    virtual ~Pretekar();
    const char* getPriezvisko();
    const char* getMeno();
    const char getPohlavie();
    unsigned int getStartCislo();
    int getDosihaCas();

private:
    const char* _priezvisko;
    const char* _meno;
    const char _pohlavie;
    unsigned int _startCislo;
    int _dosiahCas;
};
```

Pretakar.cpp

```
#include "Pretekar.h"

Pretekar::Pretekar(const char * priezvisko, const char * meno, const char pohlavie, unsigned int startCislo, int dosiahCas) :
    _priezvisko(priezvisko), _meno(meno), _pohlavie(pohlavie), _startCislo(startCislo), _dosiahCas(dosiahCas)
{
}

Pretekar::Pretekar() : _pohlavie('y')
{
}

Pretekar::~Pretekar()
{
}

const char* Pretekar::getPriezvisko()
{
    return _priezvisko;
}

const char* Pretekar::getMeno()
{
    return _meno;
}

const char Pretekar::getPohlavie()
{
    return _pohlavie;
}

unsigned int Pretekar::getStartCislo()
{
    return _startCislo;
}

int Pretekar::getDosihaCas()
{
    return _dosiahCas;
}
```

And now my main, the problem happens at lines  30 and 58 where I want to add an "Pretekar" into the array, when it happens it changes the whole array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Pretekar.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

void subor(char* argv) {
    Pretekar* pretekari[20];
    std::string menoSuboru = argv;
    std::ifstream inSubor(menoSuboru);
    std::string newLine;
    int pocitadlo = 1;
    const char* pohlavie;
    const char* meno;
    const char* priezvysko;
    while (std::getline(inSubor, newLine))
    {
        std::string buf;
        std::stringstream ss(newLine);

        std::vector<std::string> result;

        while (ss >> buf)
            result.push_back(buf);
        pohlavie = result.at(2).c_str();
        meno = result.at(1).c_str();
        priezvysko = result.at(0).c_str();
        Pretekar pretekar(priezvysko, meno, pohlavie[0], pocitadlo, 15900 + (std::rand() % (23135 - 15900 + 1)));
        pretekari[pocitadlo - 1] = &pretekar;
        pocitadlo++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<Pretekar> pretekari;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        subor(argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        std::string riadok;
        int pocitadlo = 1;
        while (getline(std::cin, riadok) && !riadok.empty())
        {
            std::string buf;
            std::stringstream ss(riadok);

            std::vector<std::string> result;

            while (ss >> buf)
                result.push_back(buf);
            std::string pohlavie = result.at(2).c_str();
            std::string meno = result.at(1).c_str();
            std::string priezvisko = result.at(0).c_str();
            Pretekar pretekar(priezvisko.c_str(), meno.c_str(), pohlavie.c_str()[0], pocitadlo, 15900 + (std::rand() % (23135 - 15900 + 1)));
            pretekari.push_back(pretekar);
            pocitadlo++;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what the array looks like after adding first and second element
[image]
[image]

Sorry for posting all of my code, but im really stuck..

Comment: Use strings instead.

Comment: Tried with strings, did the same..

Comment: `pretekari[pocitadlo - 1] = &pretekar;` that's screaming of potential bugs. Use `string`s with `append` for instance. Don't use raw pointers just yet ;)

Comment: And we have to do int with char* and char

Comment: Then learn to reallocate data, use `strncat`...

Comment: @BranislavJuriš Why is your code jumping back and forth between using `std::string` and `char *`?   You're even using `std::vector`.  Were you really given this as an assignment?

Comment: You should create Pretekar instances in heap, not in local stack by using : `pretekari[pocitadlo - 1] = new Pretekar(priezvisko.c_str(), ... )`

Comment: The only virtual in `Pretekar` is the destructor, it looks like you could just use `std::array<Pretekar, 20> pretekari`

Answer (score 4):

```
pretekari[pocitadlo - 1] = &pretekar;
```

This adds a pointer to this `pretekar` object to this array of pointers.

Unfortunately, `pretekar` is an object declared inside the loop, so the object gets destroyed at the end of the loop. The pointer in the array now points to a destroyed object, that no longer exists.

Any further attempt to dereference the pointer is undefined behavior, and will result in garbage, at best.

Comment: So, how could I create many instances of the class "Pretekar" and save them in a vector without getting garbage ?
I tried `pretekari.push_back(new Pretekar(priezvysko, meno, pohlavie[0], pocitadlo, 15900 + (std::rand() % (23135 - 15900 + 1))));`
But after the loop iterated, it was a lot of garbage

Comment: But i still need to work `Pretekar` , I need to sort them by the name and so forth ....

Comment: @BranislavJuriš *But i still need to work Pretekar* -- Then you need to rewrite your code where your object isn't being destroyed.  C++ destroys local objects that go out of scope.

Comment: If you tried using `new` and it didn't work for some reason, you can post a new, updated question and, as always, provide a [mcve] of your revised program.

Answer (score 0):

Your Pretekari constructor copied only the internal address of priezvysko, this pointer will be destroyed at the end of each while iteration.

You should use string to store your data instead of copying its temporary pointer:

In the Pretekari class, change:

```
const char* _pohlavie;
const char* _meno;
const char* _priezvysko;
```

To:

```
string _pohlavie;
string _meno;
string _priezvysko;
```

If you want to work with vector of Pretekari pointer:

```
std::vector<Pretekar *> pretekari;

.... 

pretekari.push_back( new Pretekar(...) );
```